# Unpacking android apk without changing the last modified date of files

Tags: android, compare, decompiler, last-modified, dex

I have published an android app in last year. Latest version of the apk is 3.2 (last modified date is 26th May 2012) whereas I have the source code only for 2.8 version (last modified on 15 May 2012). I am not sure what changes I have made in the code between 2.8 and 3.2.

Hence I thought of unpacking the latest apk and identify the changes. I have used APKtoJava_RC2 tool to unpack the same. I could get the source code but the last modified date of all the files are changed to current time. Hence, I could not identify the files which are updated after 2.8 version of apk.

As decompiler changes most of the code (variable names, constants...), I could not use file compare tools to identify the changes in the files between decompiled code and 2.8 version source code.

Either I need to get the original last modified date of the files so that I can manually compare the files which are updated after 2.8 version or a magic tool to compare my source code with a decompiled source code.

I have searched web a lot and came to stackoverflow with the hope that there will be some one to help me :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're stuffed. Use a version control system next time. I know that's not helpful to you right now, but it's the best advice I have.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [version control system](http://git-scm.com/), and preferably [one on the cloud](http://www.github.com/), avoids such issues. Also if you use IDE like IntelliJ IDEA, It keeps a local history of all changes made and allows you to compare and merge different versions of files.

Comment: Thanks all. I am using ADT (Previously eclipse) and eGit for version control system. I was maintaining the versions till 28 and missed to update the git for last few versions :( It is my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You could try disassembling or decompiling both versions of your apk and comparing the result, rather than trying to compare against the original source code.

Comment: Thanks JesusFreke. I am planning to do that now as I am left with no option